# How Do I use vlookup to search multiple sheets

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to populate a Case # on my contact sheet. The problem is there are three sheets the case # could be on. I have tried the formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($d2,'Jane Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP($d2,'John Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP($d2,'Bugs Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE))))
```

But I get a "too few arguments" error.

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the final IFERROR()

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($d2,'Jane Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($d2,'John Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP($d2,'Bugs Tracker'!$A$3:$O$33,4,FALSE)))
```

It's expecting another value and you just ended the formula.

Comment: Ah Ha!! Thank you!!